# How to trace/fix mouse speed changes that aren't reported by xinput?

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, plasma, xinput

Occasionally, for an unknown reason, **my mouse suddenly starts moving faster**, I think it's acceleration but it might be speed. It happens using desktop apps, and in the middle of CSGO fullscreen sessions; **it's occasional and unpredictable** and has been happening all the time I've been on Bionic AFAIR.

I'm on "KDE Frameworks 5.47.0", plasma-desktop 4:5.10, using Kubuntu 18.04.2 (bionic). The mouse is a Logitech M185 wireless.

I use something like this:

```
xinput --list-props 11 | tee xinput_mouse-11_20190731d2.out
```

to get the xinput properties for comparison (then `meld ./xinput*.out` for diffing). However they don't change when the mouse goes fast!

If I use the "Mouse - System Settings Module" (`/usr/bin/kcmshell5 mouse`) I can alter any mouse setting (eg left -> right hand), apply and get back to my desired mouse settings, ie the cursor moves at the required speed again.

So it seems that `xinput`, and `kcmshell5 mouse` both still have my desired speed/accel set. The weird thing is that none of the properties are reported as changed in `xinput` when the mouse clearly is not working the same.

Now, in investigating I've found `xset m`, this appears to do the mystery setting, the properties shown in `xinput` don't alter and the speed/accel goes to about what I think I'm getting with the transient error ... <strike>`xset` only sets AFAICT, it won't display and</strike> [see edit at end] the man page doesn't say where it is writing settings too. It sounds from passages like:

> Threshold is just an integer. The setting is applied to all connected pointing devices. xinput(1) should be used if you need device-specific settings.

That it saves settings to the same place as xinput, but then why doesn't xinput report the changes?

To repeat: if I do `xinput --watch-props 11`, then run `xset m` nothing is reported by watch-props but the mouse speed increases. However, if I then open up `kcmshell5 mouse` and toggle the "reverse scroll" property then only the following is reported:

> Property 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' changed.
>          Evdev Scrolling Distance (285): -1, -1, -1
>   Property 'Evdev Scrolling Distance' changed.
>          Evdev Scrolling Distance (285): 1, 1, 1

but we're back at the desired properties.

**Note**, I don't have an ~/.xsessionrc and the /etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc basically just sources the user rc file, I can't see anything in /etc that's doing anything to my mouse, particularly `sudo ack "xinput|mouse" /etc/X11` doesn't show any setting of the mouse.

So, any insight, how I can trace the bug that's happening (what system it's in) how I can tell quantitively the accel/speed the system is currently using (as `xinput` is clearly not showing it); and if possible how I can fix it so mouse settings don't alter themselves randomly.

Edit: the man page for xset should say "set and display", `xset q` displays the settings and corresponds to the settings made in `kcmshell5 mouse` -- I'll need to wait for the error to see if xset sees the change or not.

Comment: It may be a hardware issue. Did you try different mice?

Comment: I can't think of a mechanism by which it could be hardware, AFAIK there's no control signal sent to the mouse by setting something with xinput, it only operates on what is received; as it can be entirely put right by the software re-applying the "current" settings there seems to be no mechanism by which hardware could be affected here? No, I've not tested other mice.

Comment: I have a few suggestions from the perspective of a bug: Try libinput for xorg package `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput` as suggested in this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1574667
`xset` is a tool for `xserver ` with no proper documentation. Here it gives some insight  : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428351/how-can-i-see-the-exact-properties-that-are-set-with-xset. Another suggestion: Though your problem is different, If you have more than one screen, it may also trigger a bug: `System Settings > Displays` disable `Unknown monitor`